# get the cropped pixel size in js

Tags: javascript, html

I am using following css for the video tag

```
object-fit: cover
```

to fill the space available on the parent div. So as expected the video is cropped. I want to get how much it was cropped from left, top, bottom, right
Following is the code for displaying my video tag.

```
    <div id="pl_828213754661263600" class="playerstream" style="width: 100%; 
       height: 100%; position: relative; background-color: black; overflow: 
       hidden;"> 
    <video id="stream828213754661263600" class="stam video-cover" 
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute" autoplay="autoplay" 
    src="blob:192.168.1.9/c5e79003-120a-4906-933c-6ae198f91c33">
  </video> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Do you mind if you can share more code? How do you video I mean how to do you render video?

Comment: <div id="pl_828213754661263600" class="playerstream" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; background-color: black; overflow: hidden;">
 
 <video id="stream828213754661263600" class="stam video-cover" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute" autoplay="autoplay" src="blob:https://192.168.1.9/c5e79003-120a-4906-933c-6ae198f91c33">
</video>
</div>

Comment: Include any css with it too.